# pip Install の実行時にエラーになってしまう

Tags: python, python3, pip

Python初心者です。
cmdよりpipインストールを実行するとエラーになり対処法がわからないためご教示頂けると幸いです。

*環境*
Windows 10
Python 3.7.3
pip 19.0.3

*エラー　（pip install reportlabを実行）*

```
Collecting reportlab
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 269, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 196, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 639, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 610, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 743, in _get_pages
    page = _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 229, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 177, in _get_html_response
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 403, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 524, in request
    prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 700, in merge_environment_settings
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 761, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy):
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 745, in should_bypass_proxies
    bypass = proxy_bypass(parsed.hostname)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 95, in proxy_bypass
    return proxy_bypass_registry(host)
  File "c:\users\yamada\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 61, in proxy_bypass_registry
    'ProxyEnable')[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: FYI: 手元の環境（ Linux 5.1.18、 Python 3.7.3）では正常にreportlab-3.5.23をインストールできました。

Comment: 他のパッケージをインストール/アップデートしましたか？ その場合は正常でしたか？ またWindows自身は32bit/64bitのいずれでしょう？ そしてPythonを32bit/64bit両方や、2.7系もインストールしていたりはしませんか？ といったあたりの情報を追記してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
Windows 64bit、Python 32bitだったのでPythonを64bitに入れ直しましたが同様のエラーが発生しました。2.7は入れておりません。
また、他のパッケージのインストールもエラーとなります。

Comment: 色々試した結果、Proxy経由に設定を変えたところ問題なくインストールができました。原因はわかりませんが、一先ずうまく行ったのでこのまま使ってみたいと思います。ご協力ありがとうございました。

Comment: こんな記事がありました。[ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54577876/9014308) 本来は`REG_DWORD`であるはずの`ProxyEnable`が`REG_BINARY`になっていたのでは？というコメントがあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます、参考にさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 1):

[本家SOの類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60111154)、[コメントの類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54577876)のいずれもレジストリを書き換えて解決していました。
レジストリエディタから、`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable`の型を`REG_DWORD`に変更します。(`REG_BINARY`型になっている可能性があります)

これは推測ですが、Windows 64bit版にPython **32bit版**をインストールするとpipがネットワーク接続する時にproxyの判定でレジストリを読みに行き、エラーが発生するようです。
なので明示的にproxyを指定するとレジストリを使った判定ロジックを呼び出さずに正常動作すると予想しています。

なお本家SOではPython 32bit版をアンインストールして64bit版を入れなおしても、問題は解決しなかったと記載されています。
その後にレジストリを書き換えて解決していました。